# TCP connection and firewalls

Tags: wcf, tcp, nettcpbinding

> On the Internet, if you need fast,
>   secure server-to-server communication,
>   and you can specify which ﬁrewall
>   ports are open,  NetTcpBinding can
>   prove very valuable.

a) Is text implying that with some other connection protocols, such as HTTP, we don't need to check for open firewall ports?

b) Why would `NetTcpBinding` only be useful for server-to-server communications, but not for client-to-server communications?

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a) When you deploy to an enterprise, you usually don't have control over their external firewall. The setup of their firewall is made by network administrators following an enterprise wide policy. External firewalls almost always allow outgoing HTTP requests (otherwise you couldn't browse the web). Some corporate firewalls block outgoing TCP requests, which means you cannot use netTcpBinding. As an example, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052755/making-a-tcp-connection-through-a-restrictive-outbound-firewall) for somebody trying to deal with that issue. If you KNOW that the firewall of every one of your customers will allow outgoing TCP, then NetTcpBinding is an appropriate choice.

b) Who says NetTcpBinding is only useful for server-to-server communications? You can deploy a client-server application into an enterprise, and providing the clients and the servers are all within the intranet, then NetTcpBinding is an appropriate choice of binding.

Comment: A – so within intranet NetTcpBinding is appropriate choice for client-to-server and for server-to-server communications. But is it also an appropriate choice for internet server-to-server communications if the two servers communicate over the internet? If yes, why? B - "Who says NetTcpBinding is only useful for server-to-server communications?" Well, that quote is from Essential WCF, so i guess the author says it :)

Comment: Again, it's all about the impediments that the network allows. Server-to-server communication can use HTTP, and if it's over an internet with firewall issues then that might be the only choice. A common pattern is for the client to be outside the firewall, and a network of servers within an intranet, which is possibly what the book was alluding to.

Comment: sorry for replying so late...anyways, thank you for your help